# Kohana can't find my controllers, routes are wrong?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I'm still playing with Kohana, and found another stopper for me :-)

I've created a new simple controller called compte.php and is located inside /app/classes/controller/compte.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Compte extends Controller {

public function action_index()
{
    $this->response->body('hello, world comptes!');
}
} // End Comptes
```

Why I can't go to this controller with this url?

```
http://127.0.0.1/~user/kohana/compte/
```

This url works:

```
http://127.0.0.1/~user/kohana/
```

I've edited the routes in the bootstrap.php file but without success, sure I'm missing something ...

If I use the default route to point to my controller comptes, I can see it ok, but I want to know how to go directly to this controllers.

```
 Route::set('compte', '()') ->defaults(array( 'controller' => 'compte', 'action' => 'index', ));
```

thanks!

### EDIT

I'm getting the error 404 Not Found error from Web Server, not from Kohana

### EDIT 2

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /~user/kohana/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Also the file is located at the same level as the examples.htaccess but renamed to .htaccess, in the kohana folder

### EDIT 3

I've followed for third time the tutorial linked, the initial problem was with Apache, now the 404 is from Kohana:

```
HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: compte
```

This is my only route in bootstrap.php

```
 Route::set('compte', '') ->defaults(array( 'controller' => 'compte', 'action' => 'index', ));
```

If I enter an URL without any controller, I can see the default compte Controller, but if I use compte or comptes or whatever, always 404 not found ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding edit 3:

Your route only matches an empty URI string. 'compte' or 'comptes' are not empty strings.
If you want the route to match an empty URI as well as the URIs 'compte' and 'comptes' then use this:

```
Route::set('compte', '(compte(s))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'compte',
        'action' => 'index',
    ));
```

The whole thing is optional so it can match an empty URI. The 's' is optional too once 'compte' is present. Routing is very powerfull once you get to know it, which you can [here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/routing).

Comment: ok, thanks, now it's working. Sorry for not marking all other answers as Accepted, all of them were needed to solve the final issue. thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Route::set('compte', '') ->defaults(array( 'controller' => 'compte', 'action' => 'index', ));
```

Note that the url part is empty.

Comment: Is that a Kohana 404 not found, or a page from your webserver?

Comment: That means the error is outside of Kohana, and probably means that your .htaccess is not correct.

Comment: Could be, but why without any controller in the url Kohana receives it?

Comment: Also after updating the .htaccess file, the problem is exactly the same. See the original question for .htaccess file. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Apache is not configured to read the .htaccess file. Read the "404 errors" section here: https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/962c5f12714cb3ab146a41db61a888c2b0cc79da/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls.md

Comment: thanks for the link! I moved my kohana from /user/library to /Library/, and now Apache is reading the .htaccess, now the error 404 is from Kohana, we're progressing :-)

Comment: You shouldn't need to move your application. Are you developing on OSX? You should just edit the apache configuration to allow apache to read .htaccess. See here: http://somethingcliche.com/2010/01/21/use-htaccess-in-osx-10-6-snow-leopard/

Comment: I don't care now where my files are, I'want to try and experiment with Kohana. If I use the /Library/ directly I get the 404 from Kohana, some route is missing but I can't see nothing wrong ... After creating the .htaccess for my user and serving pages from there, know I get a 403 Forbidden from apache, but before was working, try to isolate this also. thanks

Comment: Hey mongeta, i'm almost certain your environment is not set up correctly. Here's a better tutorial: http://yardley.ca/2011/11/21/setting-up-kohana-3-2-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Hey! I was following precisely this tutorial :-) and still get the error, sure it's a stupid mistake :-)

Comment: Edited the question with more data :-)